# Disputed flag on a closed question

Tags: discussion, flagging

If some one raises a flag on a question, say then the flag is disputed and finally the question is closed. Shouldn't the user who raised the flag should get the credit of one helpful flag.

I believe closing the question implies that the flag was helpful even if it was disputed.

I am also making an assumption that disputed means that mods haven't agreed if a flag is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You flagged the question as low quality. During the post's time in the `Low Quality Posts` review queue, two users disagreed that the post was low quality, deciding instead "Looks OK". At that point the post left the queue, and your flag was marked as disputed. It wasn't until after this entire process completed that close votes started rolling in.

Comment: So close votes were not because of low quality of the question but because of any other reason.